# Build:Cannot find name '$'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS2015. After upgrade from TS 1.8 to 2.4.1 TS cannot find typing files.

```
Build:Cannot find name '$'.
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
"module": "none",
"allowJs": true,
"outFile": "app.js",
"noImplicitAny": false,
"noEmitOnError": true,
"removeComments": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5"
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please consider reading the documentation on how to update. To get you started: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by listing all ts and typings files in tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "none",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outFile": "Scripts/app.js",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },

  "files": [
    "Scripts/jquery.js",
    "Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts",
    ...
    "Scripts/main.ts"
  ]
}
```